# $P( \text{ Launch a project }|\text{ Stock increases })=0.75 * 0.6 = 0.45$, is wrong?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

[Here](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/other/total-probability-rule/) is given an example of conditional probability. If you look at this part:

[image]

If they want to find the probabilities they have written out after the graph, they're supposed to do the following calculations:

Let events $L = \text{ Launch a Project }$, $S = \text{ Stock price increases }$

Then $P(L|S)=\frac{P(S|L)P(L)}{P(S)}$

$P(S|L)= 0.75$

$P(L)= 0.6$

$P(S)=P(S|L)P(L)+P(S|L^c)P(L^c)=0.75*0.6+0.4*0.3=0.45+0.12=0.57$

So $P(L|S) = \frac{0.75*0.6}{0.57}=0.45/0.57= 0.78$

So the way they write  $P(  \text{ Launch a project }|\text{ Stock increases })=0.75 * 0.6 = 0.45$, is wrong.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also according to me it is wrong, even if I am not used to these tree representation (but sounds intuitive).

One can make also a calculation without Bayes:

$p(L|S)=\frac{p(L,S)}{p(S)}=\frac{0.75*0.6}{0.75*0.6+0.4*0.3}=\frac{0.45}{0.57}\sim 0.79$

that is what you get. The calculation they did considers only the numerator for some reason ?

Answer (score 1):

The intended calculation should have been $$\Pr[S] = \Pr[L \cap S] + \Pr[\bar L \cap S], \tag{correct}$$ rather than what they actually wrote, $$\Pr[S] = \Pr[L \mid S] + \Pr[\bar L \mid S]. \tag{incorrect}$$  In turn, what was written should have been
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[L \cap S] &= \Pr[L] \Pr[S \mid L] = (0.6) (0.75) = 0.45, \\
\Pr[\bar L \cap S] &= \Pr[\bar L] \Pr[S \mid \bar L] = (0.4) (0.3) = 0.12, \end{align} \tag{correct}$$ rather than
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[L \mid S] &= \Pr[L] \Pr[S \mid L] = (0.6) (0.75) = 0.45, \\
\Pr[\bar L \mid S] &= \Pr[\bar L] \Pr[S \mid \bar L] = (0.4) (0.3) = 0.12. \end{align} \tag{incorrect}$$

The final answer, $\Pr[S] = 0.45 + 0.12 = 0.57$, is correct, but they made typographical errors, confusing joint probability $\cap$ with conditional probability $\mid$.

To calculate $\Pr[L \mid S]$ for instance, we would need to use Bayes' rule, as you noted:  $$\Pr[L \mid S] = \frac{\Pr[S \mid L]\Pr[L]}{\Pr[S]} = \frac{0.45}{0.57}.$$

---

The point here is that if you read the actual web page, it is clear that what they really meant to write was $\cap$ instead of $|$, and "Using the decision tree, we can calculate the following **joint** probabilities."  There is no contextual interest in the posterior probability of having launched given that the stock price increased--indeed, there is no reason to be interested in such a probability because the temporal order of these events is such that the question of whether the launch occurs always precedes the impact of this decision on the stock price.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. $L$ and $S$ are not independent events here, hence what they have done is incorrect. Bayes' Theorem is the correct procedure, as you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see that your reasoning is absolutely correct is to express the data in a tabular way

[image]

As you can see, $P(L|S)=\frac{45}{57}\approx78.95\%$

Actually what they state as $P(L|S)=0.45$ is instead $P(S\cap L)$

Comment: Nice representation. I corrected a typo (I think).

Comment: @Thomas : thanks a lot